# How did this post got activity before it was posted?

Tags: support

A question on the main site by the title of "[Has it been mathematically proven that antivirus can't detect all viruses?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201992)" seems to have gotten some activity even before being posted. According to the [timeline](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/201992/timeline) it was posted at around ***2019***-01-23 01:51:09Z, however the timeline also said a comment was posted at around ***2018***-03-17 17:17:28Z, observe it was posted in 2019 and the comment was posted in 2018.

[image]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Digging into the data, the post was merged from:

[Computer Virus detection decidability proof](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/181764/computer-virus-detection-decidability-proof)

So the comments (and a now deleted answer!) were from the older post.